# How to register a thread-exit-handler in C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, synchronization

When I create a new thread I want to wait until the new thread reaches a specific point. Until now, I have solved this with a promise that is passed to the thread while the creating function waits for `future.get()`. If the initialization of the new thread fails, I set an exception to the promise so that `future.get()` will also throw an exception.

This looks something like this:

```
boost::promise<bool> promiseThreadStart;

void threadEntry();

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // Prepare promise/future
    promiseThreadStart = boost::promise<bool>();
    boost::unique_future<bool> futureThreadStarted = promiseThreadStart.get_future();

    // Start thread
    boost::thread threadInstance = boost::thread(threadEntry);

    // Wait for the thread to successfully initialize or to fail
    try {
        bool threadStarted = futureThreadStarted.get();
        // Started successfully
    }
    catch (std::exception &e) {
        // Starting the thread failed
    }

    return 0;
}

void threadEntry() {
    // Do some preparations that could possibly fail
    if (initializationFailed) {
        promiseThreadStart.set_exception(std::runtime_error("Could not start thread."));
        return;
    }

    // Thread initialized successfully
    promiseThreadStart.set_value(true);

    // Do the actual work of the thread
}
```

What upsets me here is the fact that the thread could fail during its initialization phase with an error that I do not handle. Then, I would not set the proper exception to the promise and the main-function would wait infinitely for `future.get()` to return. With this in mind, my solution seems to me quite error prone and badly designed.

I have learned about RAII and how it supplies you with exception-safety because you can clean up in the destructor. I would like to apply a similar pattern to the situation mentioned above. Therefore, I am wondering if there is something like a thread-destructor or exit-handler where I could possibly set a default exception to the promise. But anyways, using this promise/future design seems to me like a dirty workaround. So, what's the best and most elegant way to achieve exception-safe waiting?

Comment: Pass a `std::function` to your thread function maybe?

Comment: [`set_value_at_thread_exit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/promise/set_value_at_thread_exit) and [`set_exception_at_thread_exit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/promise/set_exception_at_thread_exit).

Comment: Additionally, you could use a [`std::condition_variable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) with an RAII wrapper that releases on thread exit (or manually release once your thread is "started")

Comment: I guess that if I use set_exception_at_thread_exit, the shared state of the promise will be set so I can not use set_value anymore.
And writing an RAII-wrapper means: There is no ready-to-use thread-safe solution and I have to implement it myself?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found an answer incidentally: I guess it can be done with a [`std::condition_variable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) while the waiting thread(s) can be notified with [`std::notify_all_at_thread_exit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/notify_all_at_thread_exit) if the newly created thread terminates prematurely.

Comment: Watch out for https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue3343